# Can a shell script flag have optional arguments if parsing with getopts?

Tags: shell, posix, getopts

I have a script that I want to run in three ways:

1. Without a flag -- `./script.sh`
2. With a flag but no parameter -- `./script.sh -u`
3. With a flag that takes a parameter -- `./script.sh -u username`

Is there a way to do this?

After reading some guides (examples [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)) it doesn't seem like this is a possibility, especially if I want to use `getopts`.

Can I do this with `getopts` or will I need to parse my options another way? My goal is to continue using `getopts` if I can.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I believe OP is talking about optional **arguments**, not flags. Which I don't think is possible with `getopts`.

Comment: Option arguments, not positional arguments, then? *That* makes much more sense. That said, BashFAQ #35 (linked in the question!) *does* show a (non-`getopts`-based) approach that supports their use just fine.

Comment: If my questions isn't immediately obvious, should I reword it?

Comment: Sure. Actually, I had the misunderstanding, so if you don't mind, I might try to reword a bit myself...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

The non-`getopts` example in BashFAQ #35 can cover the use case:

```
user_set=0  # 1 if any -u is given
user=       # set to specific string for -u, if provided
while :; do
  case $1 in
    -u=*) user_set=1; user=${1#*=} ;;
    -u)   user_set=1
          if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            user=$2
            shift
          fi ;;
    --)   shift; break ;;
    *)    break ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Comment: Forgot a ";;" after the "fi" ... I think.